# Stackengine not working with xstring

Tags: xetex, errors, accents, xstring, stackengine

I've been trying to make a command that allows me to automatically retypeset any V̇ in a given string, as in the font I'm using it typests as .V which isn't ideal. Using `XeLaTeX` I compiled this source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\Vh}{\stackon[1pt]{V}{.}}
\newcommand{\dothing}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{V̇}{\Vh}}

\begin{document}
\dothing{V̇aglæja}
\end{document}
```

And got the following errors:

```
Use of \\stackon doesn’t match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...d@d =#1\def\reserced@a{#2}
    \def\reserved@b{#3}\futu...
l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Argument of \\stackon has an extra }.
<inserted text>
    \par
l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \\stackon was complete.
<to be read again>
    \par
l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Undefined Control Sequence.
\xs_StrSubstitute__..._arg_iv{#4}\edef\xs_call
    {\noexpand\xs_testopt {\n...
l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Undefined Control Sequence.
\xs_StrSubstitute__...d\xs_arg_iv}}{}}\xs_call

l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
    \protect
l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Undefined Control Sequence.
\GenericError ...
    #4 \errhelp \@err@
l.9\end{document}

Undefined Control Sequence.
\GenericError ...
    \let \@err@     ...
l.9\end{document}

Undefined Control Sequence.
\GenericError ...
    \@empty \def\MessageBreak…
l.9\end{document}


Undefined Control Sequence.
\GenericError ...
    \endgroup
l.9\end{document}

Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
    \let
l.8\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 9.
<inserted text>
    \fi
<*> main.tex
```

What do these mean, and also why is this happening? Is it something to do with combining the `stackengine` and `xstring`? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\expandarg` before `\StrSubstitute` in order to expand `\Vdot`. I also added `\kern-1.5pt` to adjust the space between V and a. (I am not sure if this is a good solution or if it is effective in general, even if it works in this case.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\Vdot}{\stackon[1pt]{V}{.}\kern-1.5pt}
\newcommand{\dothing}[1]{\expandarg\StrSubstitute{#1}{V̇}{\Vdot}}

\begin{document}
 
\dothing{V̇aglæja}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I'd actually been looking for something like `\expandarg` for awhile but hadn't been able to find it; I assume it just expands the argument immediately instead of waiting until later? Again thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use a font with good anchors for the combining characters.

Alternatively, use a better method for substitutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\libertinus}{Libertinus Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dothing}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_dothing_text_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { V\x{0307} } { \c{dottedV} } \l_dothing_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_dothing_text_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_dothing_text_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\dottedV}{}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \.{}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1.1ex}%
      V\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

V̇aglæja

\dothing{V̇aglæja}

\libertinus
V̇aglæja

\end{document}
```

You can define `\dottedV` as you please, also with `stackengine` if you prefer.

[image]

We can also reinsert the right kerning, by extending the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\libertinus}{Libertinus Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dothing}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_dothing_text_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { V\x{0307} } { \c{dottedV} } \l_dothing_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_dothing_text_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_dothing_text_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkkern}{m}
 {
  \peek_catcode:NT { #1 } { \addkern{#1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\dottedV}{}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \.{}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1.1ex}%
      V\cr
    }%
  }%
  \checkkern{V}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addkern}{mm}{%
  \sbox0{#1#2}\sbox2{\hbox{#1}\hbox{#2}}%
  \kern\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax #2%
}

\begin{document}

V̇aglæja

\dothing{V̇aglæja}

Vaglæja

\libertinus
V̇aglæja

Vaglæja

\end{document}
```

Note that the kerning is not respected in the Libertinus example. It would be a good feature of XeTeX if combining characters were ignored when deciding for kerning.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I devise a  `tokcycle` environment named `\dothing` that can extend across multiple paragraphs, even to the extent of your whole document.  Just terminate with `\enddothing`.

EDITED to remove `\makeatletter` code, which has now been incorporated into `tokcycle[2021-05-27]`.  Also, eliminated one prior failure mode of `\Vdotcheck` as well as other potential failure modes (which included a space after `V` and/or a group after `V`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-27]
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\Vh}{\stackon[1pt]{V}{.}}
\def\zz#1#2{#2}
\edef\thedot{\zz V̇}
\newcommand\Vdotcheck{\tcpopliteral\z
  \ifx\thedot\z\addcytoks{\Vh}\else
  \addcytoks{V}\tcpush\z\fi}

\tokcycleenvironment\dothing
  {\ifx V##1\Vdotcheck\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}%
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
\begin{document}
\dothing
V̇aglæja 

V\today % MACRO AFTER V

V{\itshape a}bc% GROUP AFTER V

V bc% SPACE AFTER V

xV̇x VV̇% V̇  AFTER V
\enddothing
\end{document}
```

[image]